# "error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1" while installing Drox Operative

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, 32bit, shared-library

I'm trying to install Drox Operative on a laptop I just converted to running Ubuntu, and I'm getting this error whenever I try to run the game:

```
sudo ./DroxOperative./DroxOperative: error while loading shared libraries: libopenal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

From what I can tell, this is a fairly common error to run into, but I can't find how to fix it.

What's going on here and how do I fix this? I know I need to install OpenAL, but I've done that already. From what I can gather, I'm getting an error because the game is a 32-bit application, and I installed 64-bit OpenAL. Where can I find the latest version of 32-bit OpenAL

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386`



From: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454951/myth-2-on-64-bit-xubuntu-13-10-needing-libs-openal-32-bit-and-how-to-install-th

Comment: THAT DID IT! YAY NOW I CAN PLAY DROX OPERATIVE!